# Error in taking input from the BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I was asked a question regarding to find the common divisors between two numbers. I was able to figure out the logical approach using " **Sieve of Eratosthenes** " and  I was dry running my code. But my code was giving an unexpected output in the sense that it was able to figure out the no. of common divisors between two numbers. For the 1st input but for the rest it is somehow continuing with the previous value of "inner loop j" at which it was stopped for the 1st test case ; for other test cases.

**Logical approach** --> if a prime no. is a factor of given two nos. then we'll check that for every multiple of the prime no.(using array of primes[] and converting the value of multiple of primes[]=0  ) whether some of them are multiples of both the numbers or not and if yes then we'll increase the value by 1.

My question is - am using BufferedReader in the wrong way or there is some error in the code itself

Question Link-> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/common-divisors-of-two-numbers/

**Input Format**
The first line of the input contains a single integer
T
denoting the number of test cases.

The description of
T
test cases follows.

The first line of each test case contains two integers
A
and
B
.

**Output Format**
For each test case, output the number of common divisors between the given pair on a seperate line.

Constraints
1
≤
T
≤
10
^2

1
≤
A
,
B
≤
10
^9

Example
Input

3

100000 100000

12 24

747794 238336

Expected Output

36

6

2

```
try{
        
        long primes[]=new long[1000005];
                for(int i=2;i<=100000;i++){
                        primes[i]=1;
                }
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                for(int k=0;k<t;k++){
                        String s = br.readLine();
                        String s2[] = s.split(" ");
                        long a = Long.parseLong(s2[0]);
                        long b = Long.parseLong(s2[1]);
                        
                        long min = Math.min(a,b);
                        long max= Math.max(a,b);
                        System.out.println("Value of max = "+max);
                        System.out.println("Value of min = "+min);
                        long count=1;
                        for(int i=2;i*i<=min;i++){
                                if(primes[i]==1){
                                    System.out.println("Value of i = "+i);
                                        if(max%i==0 && min%i==0){
                                                count++;
                                        }
                                        for(int j=i;j*i<=min;j++){
                                                if(primes[i*j]==1){
                                                   
                                                        primes[i*j]=0;
                                                         System.out.println("Value of j = "+j);
                                                        if((max%(i*j)==0) && (min%(i*j)==0)){
                                                            
                                                                count++;
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                        System.out.println(count);
                }
    }catch(Exception e){
        return;
    }
```

My output for different values of input -

```
Value of max = 24
Value of min = 12
Value of i = 2
Value of j = 2
Value of j = 3
Value of j = 4
Value of j = 5
Value of j = 6 <------
Value of i = 3
Value of j = 3
6
Value of max = 40
Value of min = 20
Value of i = 2
Value of j = 7  <------
Value of j = 8
Value of j = 9
Value of j = 10
Value of i = 3
Value of j = 5
3
Value of max = 100
Value of min = 20
Value of i = 2
Value of i = 3
2
```

How can I figure out the mistake? I am new in using BufferedReader?

Comment: It's an algorithm issue. I think your resetting of `primes` array to all 1s should take place every time you get a new input, right after `br.readLine()`. Not a problem with buffered reader at all. You're not closing it properly though. Look up "try-with-resources".

Comment: Yes, I figured it out for my code to work fine I need to create new primes[] for every test case which (would be very inefficient) for very huge test cases. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is wrong. `BufferedReader` is working fine.
Take a simple example, say `a=131`, `b=262`, your program will return 1 as an answer but the correct answer would be `2` (1 & 131). Why is this happening?
Simply because your program misses to check for all those `primes` which are > sqrt(min) and are factors of both numbers.
To rectify this you need to check for the divisibility with those primes in a linear manner at the end as below but this will be inefficient.

```
for (int i=2; i<=min; i++)
    if (primes[i] == 1 && (max%(i)==0) && (min%(i)==0))
        ++count;
```

Also, for the correct working of above, you need to mark the `i-th` number as composite by `primes[i]=0` during each `i-th` iteration.
Also, initialization of `primes` array should be done during each test case as in the previous testcase, the `primes` array would have been modified.

```
primes[] = new long[1000005];
    for(int i=2; i<=100000; i++)
        primes[i] = 1;
```

For an efficient approach, please refer to the GFG article you shared.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out for my code to work fine I need to create new primes[] for every test case which (would be very inefficient) for very huge test cases.